# How client can connect to new room via socketio by leave all old rooms

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

i have 5 rooms on server let say "A", "B","C","D","E"

**server side**
i.e

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('New user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('User was disconnected');
    });
});
```

//function that create rooms

```
function connectSocket(data) {
    io.emit(data.device_id, data);
    console.log('room',data.device_id, 'created');
}
```

// room creation call

```
connectSocket("A");
```

**client side**

```
var socket = io(*url*);
socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Connected to server');
});
socket.on(*roomname*, function (message) {
    console.log(message);
});
```

`
**problem**

i want to switch room A to B

but before i switch i want to close all connections

i don't want to listen data from old rooms when i join new room

Comment: I am also facing the same issue 
Can plz someone explains how to use one room at a time with peace of code

Comment: @hexacyanide any help on it?

Comment: Use socket.leave(room_id) in 'disconnect' event

Answer (score 3):

I think you mixed up events with rooms. The `io.emit(data.device_id, data);` doesn't create a room, it just send the data to every connected clients, the first parameter is the name of the event, the second is the data. [Documentation](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/).

The proper way to use rooms in Socket.IO is the following:

Join a room:

```
socket.join(roomId); // roomId is a string
```

Leave a room:

```
socket.leave(roomId);
```

Send to all clients in 'game' room except sender:

```
socket.to('game').emit('nice game', "let's play a game");
```

Send to all clients in 'game' room, including sender:

```
io.in('game').emit('big-announcement', 'the game will start soon');
```

For more information check the [Socket.IO cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/#) and the docs about [rooms and namespaces](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#).

I hope it helps!

Comment: how can i create rooms on server ?
how can i join room which is just created on server from client side ? how can i leave room from client side?
note: what ever room we created on server will not close when ever we leave from client side. because multiple clients will join to get data from that room. @Tamas